# How to return distinct rows from and Entity with related Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have an Entity that has an association to other Entities (related entities). I'm trying to return distinct rows from the primary entity which needs to include the data from the related entity so I can use one the related entity's properties downstream.

Below is the statement I'm using but it is not returning any rows. What's the best way to do this?

Below is my code.

```
return context.UserDisplays.Include("CurrentJob").Where(d => d.UserName == userName).GroupBy(d => d.CurrentJob.JobNo).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - For ComplexProperty

I believe once you do a `GroupBy` all `Include` methods are ignored. So you will need to iterate the list and call the `LoadProperty` method on each item. It should look something like this

```
var list = context.UserDisplays
                  .Where(d => d.UserName == userName)
                  .GroupBy(d => d.CurrentJob.JobNo)
                  .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

foreach(var item in list)
{
   context.LoadProperty(item, "CurrentJob");
}

return list;
```

[Resource Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/28/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-2-complex-types-deferred-loading-and-explicit-loading.aspx)

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by the CurrentJobReference? Is this the related entity? If so, the ComplexProperty (CurrentJob) does not show a Load() method in intellisense. Is something missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Distinct (Set Operators) section in this article 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746
Are you asking for the Distinct UserDisplays? or the Distinct User or the Disticnt Jobs?

I would try say something like

```
var object = (from userDisplay in context.UserDisplays.Include("CurrentJob")
.Where userDisplay.UserName == userName
Select userDisplay).Distinct();
```

(sorry, im going off of my VB style but it should be about the same...)

Comment: I would also try and check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/01/14/building-custom-linq-expressions-made-easy-with-dynamicqueryable_2e00_.aspx  theres some awesome "distinct" examples near the bottom

Comment: VB style is all good...I appreciate the help. I want the distinct JobIDs from UserDisplays. There are multiple Jobs for each display. I'll check the article out and massage your example to see what I come up with and post results.

Comment: If you just want to pull the JobIDs as a list of integers and not the actual objects, then on your select line do a Select userDisplay.JobNo).Distinct(); and it will just snag those distinct Ids.